# How to vertically centre Bootstrap container in viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to vertically centre a Bootstrap container in the viewport. My code can be seen at

http://www.bootply.com/C8vhHTifcE

All my attempts to centre this have failed. Does anyone have a solution?

To clarify: I want the container vertically centered in the viewport and I want to be able to space out the rows so they fill the space.

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            A HEADING
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            AN ITEM
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            ANOTHER ITEM
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                <input value="A BUTTON" style="width:100px;" type="button">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
```

Comment: inline-styles are difficult to debug (not in the browser but in the question set) ...

Comment: The .container is always centered

Comment: Exactly! It seems to work for me too. Its all centered! http://plnkr.co/edit/iAbntofXeqD0RN14H3IG?p=preview

Comment: No! It's not centered vertically. It's little towards the bottom.

Comment: Ahh, he wants middle of viewport, vertically.

Comment: That is not the way to do it. Use no grid system here, use display:table and table-cell.

Comment: Post a fiddle with ALL the images and all the content so that it's duplicate of what you see.

Comment: Yes I want middle of viewport vertically. I am using Bootstrap everywhere on my site so am looking for a bootstrap compatible solution.

Comment: Bootstrap is a framework with CSS and javascript, it's not CSS itself or the answer to all things. You can add additional css and styles at will. Google 'centering the unknown css' and there's a bunch of samples to learn from. There is no such built in way of centering vertically in Bootstrap using only Bootstrap's classes. And using br and inline styles will make all the solutions on the instructions you find next to impossible if not impossible. Remove the br and the inline styles, create new classes and make a style sheet

Comment: I have googled and tried lots of solutions none of which work. I was hoping there might be a solution for the bootstrap container.

Comment: Load up all the images and everything in a fiddle or jsbin. There is no built in solution in Bootstrap, you have to make your own classes and adjust the given selectors with scoped css or create your own selectors or do a mixture.

Comment: Ok so your view is that there is no CSS code that can wrap mine to centre it vertically. So the answer to my question is no.

Comment: There is css but it's not part of Bootstrap and if you want to have something that works with your specific situation then a Bin or Fiddle with the images and all the html that you want vertically and horizontally centered.

Comment: It does not need to be part of bootstrap just work with bootstrap i will try and setup a fiddle

Comment: Bootply is already set up for Bootstrap. JSBin has the framework (just choose that).

Comment: Ok thanks Christina I have simplified my code considerably and put in bootply hopefully making it all a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/AGZSk1TaJc

[image]

**CSS:**

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px
}
body,
html {
    height: 100%
}
.display-table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    max-width:1170px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.display-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.display-table-cell > div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
}
.display-table-cell > div > span {
    display: table-cell;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.display-table-cell > div:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f7f7f7
}
.display-table-cell > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #eee
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container display-table text-center">
   <div class="display-table-cell">
     <div><span>A HEADING</span></div>
        <div><span>AN ITEM</span></div>
        <div><span>ANOTHER ITEM </span></div>
      <div><span><input value="A BUTTON" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span></span></span></div>
   </div>
</div>
```